# unable to change java version in windows 10 among multiple versions

Tags: windows-10, java

I am using windows 10 64-bit. I have multiple Java versions installed.

```
Java 8
Java 11
Java 17
```

Now my problem is I am able to change Java versions. When I am checking the Java Version from the command line by the command `java -version`, it shows java 17. But at the environment variables, I have set Java 8.

```
    PS C:\Users\Dell> java -version
java version "17.0.3.1" 2022-04-22 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.3.1+2-LTS-6)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.3.1+2-LTS-6, mixed mode, sharing)
```

[image]

Even in the path variables, I have also set JDK 8.

[image: Path Varriables]

Comment: You are showing the value of JAVA_HOME but not where JAVA_HOME is contained the within PATH variable.

Comment: @Ramhound
check the edit.

Comment: Try moving `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin` to be the first path in the variable. I assume you want to use Java 8 instead of Java 11 or Java 17.

Comment: @Ramhound yes are right,

Comment: Are you willing to uninstall all three versions, then reinstall Java 8, then reinstall Java 11 and Java 17?